# Space between axis title and tick labels in persp plot in R (using vis.gam from mgcv package)

Tags: r, plot, mgcv

I am making a perspective plot of my generalised additive model (GAM) named a1b, using `vis.gam()`, which in turn makes use of the `persp` function in R.

Code is as follows:

```r
library(mgcv)
vis.gam(x = a1b, 
        view = c("wbgt_max", "lag"), 
        plot.type = "persp", 
        xlab = "max WBGT (°C)", 
        ylab = "lag (days)", 
        zlab = "deaths", 
        theta = 60, 
        phi = 15, 
        r = sqrt(3), 
        d = 1, 
        type = "response", 
        ticktype = "detailed")
```

This produces the following plot:

[image]

I would like to:

1. increase the space between the axis titles and the tick labels for the x and z- axes (WBGT and deaths) and
2. increase the space between the ticks and the tick labels.

I've looked up similar posts, which suggest adding the following code to the plot (and change the values for the currently stated defaults):

```r
par(mgp=c(3,1,0))
```

like

```r
library(mgcv)
par(mgp=c(20,20,20))
vis.gam(x = a1b, 
        view = c("wbgt_max", "lag"),
        etc.
```

However, this changes nothing at all to the plot. (I tried with `c(20, 20, 20)` , smaller values and larger ones).

Would be grateful for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

I posted the above query also to the r-help mailing list, and received the following helpful [response](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2022-July/475201.html):

"R does not provide a native 3D coordinate syytem in base graphics. Therefore, persp() is rather a hack that plots everything based on its
internal code into the device. Labels are not in the marhings of the 2D coordinate system, hence the related par() are not functional.

I'd suggest to add the axis titles manually after the plot and keep the
rest unless you want to look fpr alternatives to persp()."

Answer (score 0):

1. Just try:

vis.gam(...,
zlab="n/n/n/ deaths",
...)

The axis setting parameter in par() function only works for 2D plots with function plot().

2. You can try ntick=...